# Create multiple files in a directory without change current directory

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I'm using command below in my mac machine:

```
mkdir views && touch views/layout.erb views/home.erb views/about.erb views/contact.erb
```

It's working as expected. But i'm looking for something, so that i don't have to use directory name(views) to create/touch each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
mkdir views && touch views/{layout,home,about,contact}.erb
```

Or you can change the directory in a sub-shell, so your current shell's working directory is unchanged:

```
mkdir views && (cd views && touch layout.erb home.erb about.erb contact.erb)
```

Another option is to use a loop:

```
mkdir views && for f in layout home about contact ; do touch views/${f}.erb ; done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use bash expansion to make this more concise:

```
mkdir views && touch views/{layout,home,contact}.erb
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir views && pushd views && touch layout.erb home.erb about.erb contact.erb && popd
```

Or:

```
mkdir views && (cd views && touch layout.erb home.erb about.erb contact.erb)
```